# Remove index from object

Tags: javascript, angular

I have one array like below

```
let deletedItemsArrays:any [
0: {product-id: 1, name: 'Margherita', price: 92}
1: {product-id: 2, name: 'Farm House', price: 138}
2: {product-id: 3, name: 'CHEESE N CORN', price: 200}
]
```

I want to convert it it in object so use below syntex(angular)

```
this.convertObject = {...deletedItemsArrays};
```

So output as per below

```
{
0 : {product-id: 1, name: 'Margherita', price: 92}
1 : {product-id: 2, name: 'Farm House', price: 138}
2 : {product-id: 3, name: 'CHEESE N CORN', price: 200}
}
```

I want output like below means want to remove 0,1,2,... etc index

```
{product-id: 1, name: 'Margherita', price: 92}
{product-id: 2, name: 'Farm House', price: 138}
{product-id: 3, name: 'CHEESE N CORN', price: 200}
```

Please Help me

Comment: you can't ... an Array is an object with numerical keys - and an object is a series of key/value pairs, you can't have a value without a key

Comment: I think what you did have misuse the object. Object requires key-value pair (property). Would say your desired output is impossible.

Comment: Object without a key is impossible

Comment: That's not an object, not an array, not a thing. It looks like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I am really cofused. Do you want it to be an array or an object?